# How to upload package for windows 8 application to the Windows Store

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am new to Windows 8 application development, I have created the package and I have tested by launching Windows Store Test Kit. It has passed the test, but while uploading the package to the store, its showing three four errors.

- Validation error:   All packages for this app must use the package identity name
- Validation error:   The following display name doesn't match any of your reserved names
- Validation error:   The PublisherDisplayName element in the app manifest doesn't match your publisher display name
- Validation error:   The Publisher attribute of the Identity element in the app manifest doesn't match your publisher ID, which is: CN=XX-XX-XX

I tried by uploading the different projects with different names, but I am getting the same issue. I am using Visual Studio 2012 to create the package.

Please help me to solve the issue. 
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you did not associate your app with the store.

1. Right click on your project in visual studio
2. Go to Store
3. Then Associate App with the Store...
4. Follow instructions

It will update your application manifest according to Windows Store requirements.

Once it is done, you can create a new package. Make sure you check the store deployment option during the generation wizard.

Hope this helps.